# Append two pandas DataFrame with different shapes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrame of different shapes that I am trying to append. `df2` is a subset of columns in `df1`. In the Final resultant DataFrame, I am looking for all columns in `df1` and columns from `df2`. For missing columns, the values must be `NaN`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'c0': [0, 0, 0],
                    'c1': [3, 4, 5],
                    'c2': [6, 7, 8],
                    'c3': [3, 3, 3]
                  })

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'c1': [6, 7, 8],
                    'c2': [9, 10, 11],
                  })


c0   c1  c2  c3

0    3   6   3
0    4   7   3
0    5   8   3
NaN  6   9   NaN
NaN  7   10  NaN
NaN  8   11  NaN
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2])`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
df1.append(df2)
Out[2]: 
    c0  c1  c2   c3
0  0.0   3   6  3.0
1  0.0   4   7  3.0
2  0.0   5   8  3.0
0  NaN   6   9  NaN
1  NaN   7  10  NaN
2  NaN   8  11  NaN
```

Comment: `append` is deprecated, use `concat`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `merge` from Pandas :

```py
df1.merge(df2, how="outer")
Out[3]: 
    c0  c1  c2   c3
0  0.0   3   6  3.0
1  0.0   4   7  3.0
2  0.0   5   8  3.0
3  NaN   6   9  NaN
4  NaN   7  10  NaN
5  NaN   8  11  NaN
```

You can find more documentation on how merge works [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: I think this is incorrect, this will give weird results in case of matching values.

Comment: You're right, in some case it can lead to unexpected/undesired results if (for instance) there a common row between df1 and df2 (not totally unexpected, but not a strict appending).